# Can we publish asp.net website application refer another project to azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

My solution in visual studio 2017 contains two projects:

1. One Asp.NET website application
2. One C# library that the application above will refer. This library will do some consultant logic.

My problem is that when I publish a website that doesn't refer to another project to Azure, It works well. But if I refer to another project in the asp.net application, then the website published to Azure will throw a runtime error. While it works well locally. The runtime error is that

> "Could not load file or assembly 'DataSchemas' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. "

"DataSchemas" is one of the dll my project will refer to.

So what should I do to publish an Asp.NET application that refers to another project to Azure?

Comment: Most likely a target format issue, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551816/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-windows-azure-website)

Comment: that assembly should have "Copy Local" property true to get copied during the build

Comment: @Aravind that is not the error you would get if the assembly was not there at all.

Comment: I agree @Crowcoder this error should not occur for a missing assembly.  Just to make sure you have the necessary assemblies  deployed in azure . Could you please look into  the azure website/bin under app websites in visual studio  2017 cloud explorer. The link mentioned  for a possible issue/resolution does make a lot of sense  , but if this was the situation(mismatch of cpu 32/64 bit) , it  would have thrown exception locally as well. I created a similar setup and throws a runtime error(same as mentioned) locally as well.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for your solution. I just change (Settings->Application Settings->Platform) from 32-bit to 64-bit, and It works well. Thanks for your advice!